# React-native Animating Circular progress not work properly

Tags: react-native

```
I want to draw a animated circuler progress on which run with duration when i start animation it show not properly After Complete Animation it show only a 

import { AnimatedCircularProgress } from 'react-native-circular-progress';
import React,{Component} from 'react';
         import PercentageCircle from 'react-native-percentage-circle';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
export default class FirstScreen extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
       this.circularProgress.performLinearAnimation(100, 8000);

    }
render() {
    return (
       <View>
 <AnimatedCircularProgress
  size={120}
  width={15}
  fill={100}
  tintColor="#00e0ff"
  backgroundColor="#3d5875" 
  ref={(AnimatedCircularProgress) => { this.circularProgress = AnimatedCircularProgress; }}/>
       </View>
    );
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('GTproject', () =>FirstScreen);

The link i follow is https://github.com/bgryszko/react-native-circular-progress
The Screen shot of animation from start to end first it start a circle from 0 but one line from an other side is also with this circle as in show below link
```

First it show as https://ibb.co/kEZ2za
    Then it show as 
    https://pictub.club/image/79MtJC
    Then after complete circle it show only line 
    https://pictub.club/image/79M9WG

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like this bug encountered with recent React Native versions on Android: https://github.com/bgryszko/react-native-circular-progress/issues/64

It's fixed in this fork: https://github.com/andreiciceu/react-native-circular-progress